# azure authentication web app localhost reply url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, web

I've created a web app using Azure auth.
It's working fine locally but when published the auth reply url is looking for the localhost. 
I've added the correct reply url to Azure portal and I can get it to work if I add either the locahost or requireUrl to the top of the list.

Searching for the fix says I need to use web.config transforms to set the reply url for either localhost or deployed app.

I can't get it to work.
I'm using:

```
<Configuration>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <wsFederation reply="localhost" realm="localhost" issuer="https://login.microsoftonline.com/"/>
     </federationConfiguration>
</system.identityModel.services>
</configuration>
```

Just for testing I'm have the deployedURL set in top of the list on Azure reply urls and its working fine for the deployed app but the local development version is redirecting to the deployedURL after login.

I thought the above web.config code would redirect the local development version to stay local.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else that finds the question I was using the wrong method for OWIN.
Resolution was to add the replyUri to the Start.Auth.cs

`private static string redirecturi = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUrl"];`

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                RedirectUri = redirecturi
            });
    }
```

Then just add it to the web.config.

```
<appSettings>
<add key ="ida:RedirectUrl" value="https://localhost:44312/"/>
</appSettings>
```

And transform in the web.config.release or any other transform file like this;

`<add key="ida:RedirectUrl" value="APP URL ADDED TO AZURE REPLY URLS" />`

Answer (score 0):

Thx for sharing this, helped me to get a bearing with the issue. You can generalize the solution by using a more precise transformation request with the web.release.config file. If you use a statement like this:
`<add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="https://mytestwebsite.azurewebsites.net" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>`
the correct key-value pair gets modified, no need to have it as the first key-value pair in the `<appSettings />` section. You can add a 2nd transformation to also adapt the PostLogoutRedirectUri: `<add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://mytestwebsite.azurewebsites.net" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>`

Summary:
Add these lines to the `<configuration />` section of the web.release.config template file to adapt both redirect Uri:

`<appSettings>
    <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="THE URL OF THE AZURE WEB SITE AS SHOWN IN THE PUBLISH PROFILE" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
    <add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="THE URL OF THE AZURE WEB SITE AS SHOWN IN THE PUBLISH PROFILE" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
</appSettings>`

For more info about this aspect of the Transformation functionality see MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd465326.aspx#Locator%20Attribute%20Syntax